# Lubuntu compaq nc6000 WiFi Driver Help

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP Compaq NC 6000.

Currently, everything except WiFi works well. I've looked online at forums both for the card (Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller) and the computer, but I am not sure how to install the drivers. Can someone walk me through the installation in a step-by-step method?

Also, there's a WiFi button on the laptop that is supposed to light up when pressed, but that does not happen.

Comment: When I click that link and then select network drivers, it asks me to select from among several different wireless devices. Since we don't know for sure which you have, let's ask your system to tell us. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Edit your question to add the result. Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, @Tom! I went ahead and edited your post a bit to make it cleaner and easier to read. I also added my guess to the Wireless card, which is the same as what is the original card. If it's not, feel free to change it using the `Edit` button. I also removed your question about the graphics card. If you want to ask about it, open a new question. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask! We're here to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please get a temporary internet connection by ethernet or any other means. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

Detach the ethernet or other connection, reboot and your wireless should be working.